# Wolfram Alpha Competitors

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Are there any sites that are similar to Wolfram Alpha, or is it currently unique?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is the only of it's kind, when it comes to understanding chemical reactions, mathematical formulas, comparing objects etc.

The search engine itself is not unique and most of the data you could get else where. But the way that it tries to understand your statement and group relevant info with graphs etc. only showing 1 result is not anything I've seen or heard about anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the biggest competitor would be [Google Squared](http://www.google.com/squared), but it doesn't do computations or graphing or stuff like that. It just fills tables with information (like U.S. presidents and their date of birth, time in office, vice president, etc.)

Edit: [Google Squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Squared) was shut down in September 2011

Comment: Link is now broken.

Comment: added a note and link to wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

[Kngine](http://kngine.com/) used to be a semantic web search and question answering engine, and its [Stats](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2010/04/27/watch-wolframalpha-announcing-kngine-stats/) platform was targeting features similar to Wolfram Alpha. However, it seems their VC is currently focusing their efforts on mobile platforms.